# Как с помощью boost.asio подключиться к source-specific multicast

Tags: c++, сокет, сеть, boost, asio

Как с помощью boost.asio подключиться к source-specific multicast и начать приём данных?

С помощью обычных сокетов это делается так:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  char group_ip[] = "239.195.1.131";
  char source_ip[] = "91.203.255.225";
  int port = 17003;
  char interface_name[] = "eth0";

  int ifname_number = if_nametoindex(interface_name);
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

  struct sockaddr_in group_addr;
  group_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group_ip);
  group_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  group_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

  struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
  source_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_ip);
  source_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  source_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

  int on = 1;
  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
  setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVTTL, &on, sizeof(on));

  bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

  struct group_source_req gsreq;
  memset(&gsreq, 0, sizeof(struct group_source_req));
  memcpy(&(gsreq.gsr_source), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &source_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  memcpy(&(gsreq.gsr_group), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

  gsreq.gsr_interface = ifname_number;
  setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP, (void *)&gsreq, (socklen_t) sizeof(struct group_source_req));

  char buf[4096];
  while(1)
  {
    socklen_t addr_size;
    struct sockaddr sAddr;
    int rd = recvfrom(sock, buf, 4096, 0, &sAddr, &addr_size);
    if(rd > 0)
      printf("%02X\n", *(unsigned int *) buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, а проверить негде, то для SSM нужно просто дополнительно назначить опции сокету, но нет механизма для этого?

Так класс для представления опции делается просто, нужно реализовать структуру со следующим интерфейсом

- `template<typename Protocol> int level(const Protocol&) const` - определяет уровень (IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_TCP, SOL_SOCKET и так далее)
- `template<typename Protocol> int name(const Protocol&) const` - замысловато, но это ID опции (TCP_CORK, MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP)
- `template<typename Protocol> group_source_req* data(const Protocol&)` и
- `template<typename Protocol> const group_source_req* data(const Protocol&) const` - сами данные опции
- `template<typename Protocol> std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const` - вернёт размер данных
- `template<typename Protocol> void resize(const Protocol&, std::size_t s)` - не совсем понимаю, просто проверять `sizeof(data) == s` и бросать исключение, если не выполняется.

Собственно реализация опции будет такой:

```
// Просто для помощи ради
using group_source_req_t = struct group_source_req;

// Костыль для ASIO_OS_DEF, что бы можно было на разных системах примерно одинаково работать
// типа если только опция отличается, но не данные. В данном случае можно обойтись вообще без этого
#define ASIO_OS_DEF_MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP

struct mcast_join_source_group
{
    mcast_join_source_group()
        : m_data()
    {}

    mcast_join_source_group(std::string &source_ip, std::string &group_ip, int port, std::string &interface_name)
        : mcast_join_source_group()
    {
          int ifname_number = if_nametoindex(interface_name.c_str());

          struct sockaddr_in group_addr;
          group_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group_ip.c_str());
          group_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
          group_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

          struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
          source_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_ip.c_str());
          source_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
          source_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

          memcpy(&(m_data.gsr_source), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &source_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
          memcpy(&(m_data.gsr_group), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

          m_data.gsr_interface = ifname_number;
    }

    // Можно объявить вспомогательные методы для правки отдельных значений или всех полей

    template<typename Protocol>
    int level(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return ASIO_OS_DEF(IPPROTO_IP);
    }

    template<typename Protocol>
    int name(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return ASIO_OS_DEF(MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP);
    }

    template<typename Protocol>
    group_source_req_t* data(const Protocol&)
    {
        return &m_data;
    }

    template<typename Protocol>
    const group_source_req_t* data(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return &m_data;
    }

    template<typename Protocol>
    std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const
    {
        return sizeof(m_data);
    }

    template<typename Protocol>
    void resize(const Protocol&, std::size_t s)
    {
        if (s != sizeof(m_data))
        {
            std::length_error ex("mcast_join_source_group socket option resize");
            asio::detail::throw_exception(ex);
        }
    }

private:
    group_source_req_t m_data;
};
```

Ну а пользоваться как-то так:

```
socket.set_option(mcast_join_source_group("91.203.255.225", "239.195.1.131", 17003, "vlan389"));
```

Для установки

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
```

нужно позвать

```
socket.set_option(asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
```

Для опций:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVTTL, &on, sizeof(on));
```

нужно создать свои на основе `asio::detail::socket_option::boolean` примерно так:

```
#define ASIO_OS_DEF_SO_TIMESTAMP SO_TIMESTAMP

typedef asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<
        ASIO_OS_DEF(SOL_SOCKET), ASIO_OS_DEF(SO_TIMESTAMP)> so_timestamp;

#define ASIO_OS_DEF_IP_RECVTTL IP_RECVTTL

typedef asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<
        ASIO_OS_DEF(IPPROTO_IP), ASIO_OS_DEF(IP_RECVTTL)> ip_recvttl;
```

Код на компилябельность не проверялся, возможны нюансы, но подход, думаю, понятен. Чуть более чисто, особенно в части адресов, можно сделать подглядывая на ip/detail/socket_option.hpp, например используя `boost::ip::address`

Comment: Спасибо, @Monah. Код заработал. Вот только макросы, типа ASIO_OS_DEF() не удалось использовать, видимо, потому что они из Asio и в Boost.Asio их нет, либо я их там не нашёл))

Comment: Возможно :) я standalone Asio использую (точнее игрался больше), так как он лучше с C++11 интегрируется. Но если закрыть глаза на возможную переносимость, то можно забить и использовать напрямую IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVTTL и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Как выяснилось, в boost.asio нет нативных методов подключения к source-specific multicast (ssm, IGMPv3). Однако, существует возможность обойти это ограничение. Для этого необходимо:

### 1 вариант.

1. создать нативный сокет с помощью кода, приведённого в вопросе выше;
2. назначить нативный сокет объекту `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`;
3. работать с полученным бустовым сокетом средствами boost.asio

   ```
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <sys/un.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <net/if.h>
   #include <arpa/inet.h>

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   #include <string>
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>

   //get source specific multicast native socket
   int get_ssm_native_socket(std::string &source_ip, std::string &group_ip, int port, std::string &interface_name)
   {
     int ifname_number = if_nametoindex(interface_name.c_str());
     int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

     struct sockaddr_in group_addr;
     group_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group_ip.c_str());
     group_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
     group_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

     struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
     source_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_ip.c_str());
     source_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
     source_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

     int on = 1;
     setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
     setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
     setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVTTL, &on, sizeof(on));

     bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

     struct group_source_req gsreq;
     memset(&gsreq, 0, sizeof(struct group_source_req));
     memcpy(&(gsreq.gsr_source), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &source_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
     memcpy(&(gsreq.gsr_group), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

     gsreq.gsr_interface = ifname_number;
     setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP, (void *)&gsreq, (socklen_t) sizeof(struct group_source_req));

     return sock;
   }

   void do_receive_incr(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket &sock)
   {
     char buf[4096];
     boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint ep;
     sock.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 4096), ep, [&buf, &sock](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd){
       if(!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
       {
         printf("%02X\n", *(unsigned int *) buf);
       }
       do_receive_incr(sock);
     });
   }

   int main()
   {
     std::string group_ip("239.195.1.131");
     std::string source_ip("91.203.255.225");
     int port = 17003;
     std::string interface_name("vlan389");

     //get source specific multicast native socket
     int native_sock = get_ssm_native_socket(source_ip, group_ip, port, interface_name);

     boost::asio::io_service io_service;
     boost::asio::ip::udp::socket sock(io_service);
     sock.assign(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), native_sock);

     do_receive_incr(sock);
     io_service.run();

     return 0;
   }
   ```

---

### 2 вариант

вариант кода предложен [Monah Tuk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189892/monah-tuk)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/socket_base.hpp>

using namespace std;

using group_source_req_t = struct group_source_req;

struct mcast_join_source_group
{
  mcast_join_source_group()
    : m_data()
  {}

  mcast_join_source_group(std::string &source_ip, std::string &group_ip, int port, std::string &interface_name)
    : mcast_join_source_group()
  {
    int ifname_number = if_nametoindex(interface_name.c_str());

    struct sockaddr_in group_addr;
    group_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(group_ip.c_str());
    group_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    group_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
    source_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(source_ip.c_str());
    source_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    source_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    memcpy(&(m_data.gsr_source), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &source_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memcpy(&(m_data.gsr_group), (struct sockaddr_storage *) &group_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    m_data.gsr_interface = ifname_number;
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  int level(const Protocol&) const
  {
    return IPPROTO_IP;
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  int name(const Protocol&) const
  {
    return MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP;
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  group_source_req_t* data(const Protocol&)
  {
    return &m_data;
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  const group_source_req_t* data(const Protocol&) const
  {
    return &m_data;
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const
  {
    return sizeof(m_data);
  }

  template<typename Protocol>
  void resize(const Protocol&, std::size_t s)
  {
    if (s != sizeof(m_data))
    {
      std::length_error ex("mcast_join_source_group socket option resize");
      boost::asio::detail::throw_exception(ex);
    }
  }

private:
  group_source_req_t m_data;
};

typedef boost::asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP> so_timestamp;
typedef boost::asio::detail::socket_option::boolean<IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVTTL> so_recvttl;

void do_receive_incr(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket &sock)
{
  char buf[4096];
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint ep;
  sock.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 4096), ep, [&buf, &sock](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd){
    if(!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
    {
      printf("%02X\n", *(unsigned int *) buf);
    }
    do_receive_incr(sock);
  });
}

int main()
{
  std::string group_ip("239.195.1.131");
  std::string source_ip("91.203.255.225");
  int port = 17003;
  std::string interface_name("vlan389");

  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket sock(io_service);
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(group_ip.c_str()), port);
  sock.open(ep.protocol());
  sock.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
  sock.set_option(so_recvttl(true));
  sock.set_option(so_timestamp(true));
  sock.bind(ep);
  sock.set_option(mcast_join_source_group(source_ip, group_ip, port, interface_name));

  do_receive_incr(sock);
  io_service.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В boost.asio всё построено на асинхронных операциях. Вам необходимо назначить callback для подключения клиента, для чтения данных (записи). Вы можете изучить этот пример: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: Кэп, уже б тогда вот эту ссылку давали)) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp, но здесь, как я понимаю, приведён пример для any source multicast. Спасибо, но ваш комментарий - в молоко)

Comment: Могу ещё посоветовать вот эту ссылку на похожий вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637010/source-specific-multicast-using-boost